# Emacs Orgmode, what does the `/` mean in a repeating task

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using Emacs Orgmode 9.1.3 to track habit and I saw a very useful habit [template](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#CaptureTemplates) below. However I was not sure what the forward slash `/` meant in the date.

```
* NEXT HABIT
[2017-12-07 Thu 10:26]

SCHEDULED: <2017-12-07 Thu .+1d/3d>
:PROPERTIES:
:STYLE: habit
:REPEAT_TO_STATE: NEXT
:END:
```

I read through the org [documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html) but there is no mention of the forward slash in setting a repeated task.

There is a reference to some sort of reminder like this:

```
DEADLINE: <2005-10-01 Sat +1m -3d>.
```

which will provide a reminder three days in advance of a task due date.

Does anyone know what the forward slash does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You looked in the wrong section of the documentation: this notation applies to [habits](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-your-habits.html#Tracking-your-habits) where you find:

> The TODO may also have minimum and maximum ranges specified by using the syntax ‘.+2d/3d’, which says that you want to do the task at least every three days, but at most every two days.